# C# Run my visual studio executable as administrator

Tags: c#, sql, installation

Hi i have created my visual studio program and if i run it as normal it works perfectly. But the problem comes in when i create a setup installation for this program. It successfully installs my program but i cannot get the program to run as administrator and thus my sql statements wont work. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: yes will add the exception here:operation must use an updateable query

Comment: This seems a bit back to front. Shouldn't the question be how to set up the database to accept connections from this non-privileged application? Or is it required to be admin?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: Are you using Windows Credential for the database or SQL Credentials.  Admin rights are different in SQL than windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to pinpoint the fault but I have a feeling you have asked an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question where running with and without elevated privileges (often wrongly called administrator). Making an installation program an installing probably has nothing to do with it. Maybe you are starting VS with elevated privileges without thinking about it?

Try to start the program directly and not through VS. Find the output folder (`yourproject\bin\debug\yourprogram.exe`) and run it. Does it work properly? Then it works.
Now try to start it with elevated privileges (admin) (ctrl-shift-enter or ctrl-shift-doubleclick). Does it work as it should? If it does, your problem has nothing to do with privileges.
So then you might have side effects by the installation. An installed file is in another directory. Do you have hard coded relative paths?